# PREGUNTA BASICA LINUX LINEA DE COMANDOS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

mi consulta es la siguiente. Soy novato en linux y linea de comandos, y creando mis primeras carpetas, moviendolas etc, todo el tiempo me aparece que tengo permisos denegados. Mi consulta es saber que puedo hacer , creo que el comando chmod no me sirve y luego tambien use sudo visudo y le di permiso al usuario ( que soy yo mismo con el superusuario), le di el comando NOPSSWD: ALL y sigue igual. Alguna idea? Gracias.

Comment: Hola. Indica él o los comandos que fallan y cuál es el error.  Normalmente si ejecutas `sudo elComando losParametros` debería funcionar,  **para ese comando**, una vez hayas ingresado la contraseña del super usuario. No te pongas a dar permisos a mansalva.

Comment: Buenas tardes. Los comandos que fallan son eliminar directorios (creados arbitrariamente de prueba, no los vitales), crear directorios, entre otras cosas. Por eso pregunto que es lo que puede ser, para solucionarlo.

Comment: Solo para agregar, no corre riesgo ningún sistema, es una simulación en VirtualBox.

Comment: Sin ver qué comandos son y qué mensajes de error estás teniendo, no te podemos decir lo que pueda ser, pues no somos adivinos.

Comment: Si eres un principiante y estás practicando a crear directories etc, lo mejor que puedes hacer es mantenerte en tu directorio `home` ya que ahí vas a tener permisos de crear/borrar sin problemas.

Comment: hola como se me encuentra para poder moverse de linux es necesario utilizar el comando cd dependiendo de su usuario depende de la carpeta que vas a crear o archivo para crear un archivo lo puedes hacer por nano o vim

Comment: `cd` el de cambiar directorio/carpeta asi sin parametros te lleva a tu "home" en esa carpeta/directorio podes crear, borrar , mover, renombrar archivos. los mensajes de permisos denegado pueden indicar que o tu usuario no tiene permisos, o que el volumen ( el "disco" ) se ha montado en sólo lectura